# Variadic constructor issue

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I've been working on a project, but I got a weird error. I can't pass 2 Shader instances to a variadic constructor, even though it says it supports 2 Shader parameters.

Exact error message:
**E0289 no instance of constructor "Program::Program" matches the argument list
argument types are: (Shader, Shader)**

Here is code:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "Renderer.h"
#include "Shader.h"

class Program
{
public:
    template<Shader&... shaders>
    Program()
    {
        GLCall(m_RendererID = glCreateProgram());
        AssignShaders(shaders...);
        GLCall(glLinkProgram(m_RendererID));
        GLCall(glValidateProgram(m_RendererID));
        GLCall(glUseProgram(m_RendererID));
    }

    Program(const std::string& vertexShaderFilepath, const std::string& fragmentShaderFilepath)
    {
        Shader vertexShader(vertexShaderFilepath, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        Shader fragmentShader(fragmentShaderFilepath, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        Program(vertexShader, fragmentShader); // error is here
    }

private:
    unsigned int m_RendererID;

    template<typename First, typename ...Shaders>
    void AssignShaders(First& first, const Shaders&... other)
    {
        Shader& shader = (Shader&)first;
        GLCall(glAttachShader(m_RendererID, shader.GetRendererID()));
        AssignShaders(other...);
    }

    void AssignShaders() {};
};
```

Here is the line which calls the Program constructor:

```cpp
Program program("resources/shaders/basic_vert.glsl", "resources/shaders/basic_frag.glsl");
```

Comment: Because the shown code does not meet all requirements for a [mre], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you until you [edit] it so it does. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: There is a *whole bunch* of things wrong with that code. Do you have experience with non-variadic templates? It might be easier for you to understand variadic templates once you have more familiarity with the core concepts behind C++ templates.

Comment: `Program(vertexShader, fragmentShader);` there is no constructor that takes two `Shader` parameters.  There is a templated constructor but that takes __no__ parameters.  Also the call `Program(vertexShader, fragmentShader);` is not a delegating constructor and will merely create a new temporary `Program` and then destroy it. See __Delegating constructor__ in here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor is missing an argument list. It got a variadic template parameter, but an explicitly empty argument list.

Apart from that, as @richardcritten mentioned, you didn't delegate the constructor as you intended, but would have created a temporary instance of `Program` instead. Delegate (by using initializer list), or call `AssignShaders` directly.

Also don't forget to call `glDeleteProgram` in the destructor of this class, or you will leak OpenGL resources!